# Finding the determinant of $A^n.$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am asked to find the determinant of $A^n$ where $A$ is

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -3 & 0 \\
1 & 3 & -1 \\
-2 & -2 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}  $$

The eigenvalues are $\lambda = -1,2(repeated)$. When $\lambda = -1$ the eigenvector is

$$v_{1}= \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
1 
\end{bmatrix}  $$

When $\lambda = 2$

$$v_{2}= \begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
1 \\
0 
\end{bmatrix}  $$

The problem is that I need to get a third eigenvector to get matrix $P$ for the matrix power formula $A^n=PD^{n}P^{-1}$. I did some research and found that you can get the third eigenvector by doing the following

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}   \begin{bmatrix}
a \\
b \\
c 
\end{bmatrix}  =\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
1 \\
0 
\end{bmatrix}  $$

Where $$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$$ is the final matrix I got after doing Gaussian reduction for $\lambda = 2$. It all came down to

$$\begin{cases} a+b=-1 \\ c=1 \end{cases}$$

Now the problem is that $v_{3}$ splits into two different vectors because of $a=-1-b$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
0 \\
1 
\end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
0 \\
0 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Am I not understanding something? Any suggestions on how to find $v_{3}$?

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing after "found that you can get the third eigenvector by doing the following" but anyway, your matrix is not diagonalizable. The eigenspace for $2$ is the line spanned by $v_2$, it is not a plane, there is no "$v_3$". Simply use $\det(A^n)=(\det A)^n.$

Comment: Yes, I think it does. Thank you